# add inserted on column for clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

with other databases, you would ad an inserted_on column to a create table with query with `inserted_on DateTime DEFAULT now()`.

However it seems that clickhouse evaluates that column at every query; I am getting the current time every time.

table structure

```
create table main.contracts(
bk_number UInt64,
bk_timestamp DateTime,
bk_hash String,
address String,
inserted_on DateTime DEFAULT now()
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(bk_timestamp)
ORDER BY (bk_number, bk_timestamp);
```

Comment: please share the table strucure.

Comment: it's only if you used `alter ... add column` you can use `alter table ... materialize column` or `alter table ... update inserted_on = inserted_on where 1`

Comment: @DennyCrane i did. that seems like an odd logic. thanks!

Comment: this logic allows to add columns instantly, without changing the old data

Answer (score 0):

I re-created your scenario and it works for me with no problems.

**Table Structure:**

```
create table contracts(
bk_number UInt64,
bk_timestamp DateTime,
inserted_on DateTime DEFAULT now()
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(bk_timestamp)
ORDER BY (bk_number, bk_timestamp);
```

**Insert Queries:**

```
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (123,'2023-02-14 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (456,'2023-02-14 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (789,'2023-02-14 03:00:00');
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (101,'2023-02-14 04:00:00');
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (102,'2023-02-14 05:00:00');
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (103,'2023-02-14 06:00:00');
INSERT INTO contracts (bk_number,bk_timestamp) VALUES (104,'2023-02-14 07:00:00');
```

**The Result:**

```
SELECT NOW();
┌───────────────now()─┐
│ 2023-02-15 04:17:51 │
└─────────────────────┘

SELECT * FROM contracts;

┌─bk_number─┬────────bk_timestamp─┬─────────inserted_on─┐
│       101 │ 2023-02-14 04:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:08:39 │
│       102 │ 2023-02-14 05:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:08:39 │
│       103 │ 2023-02-14 06:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:08:39 │
│       104 │ 2023-02-14 07:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:09:30 │
│       123 │ 2023-02-14 01:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:07:33 │
│       456 │ 2023-02-14 02:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:08:39 │
│       789 │ 2023-02-14 03:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:08:39 │
└───────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE bk_number = 123;

┌─bk_number─┬────────bk_timestamp─┬─────────inserted_on─┐
│       123 │ 2023-02-14 01:00:00 │ 2023-02-15 04:07:33 │
└───────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

**Suggestion:**

If the table is not too big I would recommend running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` once.
Check what OPTIMIZE does over here -
[Clickhouse Docs/Optimize](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/optimize)